# Trying to query VPC flow logs which lies in S3 via Athena

Tags: amazon-s3, parquet, aws-glue, amazon-athena, amazon-vpc

1. I have created a S3, pointed VPC flow logs into S3
2. Created Athena, added database and table - chose the data format as PARQUET
3. Flow logs are getting generated and are stored in S3.

I fired a simple SQL query and got the below result.

> Your query has the following error(s): HIVE_CANNOT_OPEN_SPLIT: Error opening Hive split s3://.../b22aac6f-bd90-4b1b-ba4f-7bb72ab7447a.txt (offset=0, length=32): s3://.../b22aac6f-bd90-4b1b-ba4f-7bb72ab7447a.txt is not a Parquet file. expected magic number at tail [80, 65, 82, 49] but found [104, 101, 110, 97] This query ran against the "vpc_flow_logs_for_athena" database, unless qualified by the query. Please post the error message on our forum or contact customer support with Query Id: 75ede011-ca86-4455-b0cd-ff6917a05b9c. –

Can someone please help here on ATHENA?

[image: Athena error]

Comment: Your query has the following error(s):

HIVE_CANNOT_OPEN_SPLIT: Error opening Hive split s3://********************/b22aac6f-bd90-4b1b-ba4f-7bb72ab7447a.txt (offset=0, length=32): s3://********************/b22aac6f-bd90-4b1b-ba4f-7bb72ab7447a.txt is not a Parquet file. expected magic number at tail [80, 65, 82, 49] but found [104, 101, 110, 97]

This query ran against the "vpc_flow_logs_for_athena" database, unless qualified by the query. Please post the error message on our forum or contact customer support with Query Id: 75ede011-ca86-4455-b0cd-ff6917a05b9c.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62583152/edit) your question instead of posting more information in a comment.  It will make it far easier to read.

Comment: The error is saying that the input file "is not a Parquet file". Please edit your question to include the command you used to create the `mycatalogtable`, and let us know whether you wrote that command yourself or copied it from somewhere (since it seems to be incorrect).

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the error message it is evident that the table storage is defined as parquet although underlying data is a text file which in this case is `s3://.../b22aac6f-bd90-4b1b-ba4f-7bb72ab7447a.txt` .

Please refer to this [article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/vpc-flow-logs.html) or [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/analyzing-vpc-flow-logs-got-easier-with-support-for-s3-as-a-destination/) which explains on how you can query VPC Flow logs using Athena.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at this [codeburst article](https://codeburst.io/network-monitoring-with-aws-vpc-flow-logs-and-amazon-athena-de94969f4175) as well, its step-by-step guide about Network monitoring with AWS VPC Flow Logs and Amazon Athena.